# UISearchbar Search in all fields in swift 3

Tags: swift3, uisearchbar

I've got a tableview showing some data and I filter the shown data uisng UISearchbar. Each data struct consists of different values and

```
struct Cake {
    var name = String()
    var size = String()
    var filling = String()
}
```

When a user starts typing I don't know whether he is filtering for name, size or filling. I don't want to use a scopebar. Is there a way to filter for various fields at the same time in swift 3?

This is the code I use to filter:

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {

    if searchController.searchBar.text! == "" {
        filteredCakes = cakes
    } else {
    // Filter the results
        filteredCakes = cakes.filter { $0.name.lowercased().contains(searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercased()) }
    }

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController)
{
    guard let searchedText = searchController.searchBar.text?.lowercased() else {return}

    filteredCakes = cakes.filter 
    { 
        $0.name.lowercased().contains(searchedText) ||
        $0.size.lowercased().contains(searchedText) ||
        $0.filling.lowercased().contains(searchedText)
    }

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```